# How Implement a simple 'Reactive extension'-like functions in .net3.5 by self

Tags: .net-3.5, lambda, system.reactive

I can't persuable my boss to accept the Rx libraries installed in our product, so either for study or coding convinient, I prefer to implement some simple functions like provided in official Rx, I just pick 2 here which exactly what I need now (I already implemented some basic concept like IObservable, IObserver, ISubject):

```
Where<TSource>(IObservable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
Timeout<TSource>(IObservable<TSource>, DateTimeOffset)
```

I take some time to think how implement the 'Where' but couldn't get any idea even read some ILSpy code, afterall, it's not like the IEnumerable, could somebody give some hint?

Comment: If your boss won't let you use Rx... well, implementing yourself is unlikely to be a better way to go. I would work harder at convincing him if I was you. It will be a lot cheaper for him!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got some idea on implementing it via a `TempObservable<T>` which is quite simple and the sample code is like below:

```
private class TempObservable<T> : ISubject<T>
    {
        private List<IObserver<T>> observers = new List<IObserver<T>>();
        //private IObserver<T> observer;

        #region IObservable<T> Members

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            this.observers.Add(observer);
            return new UnSubscribe<T>(this.observers, observer);
        }

        #endregion


        #region IObserver<T> Members

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception e)
        {
            this.observers.ForEach((ob) => ob.OnError(e));
        }

        public void OnNext(T value)
        {
            this.observers.ForEach((ob) => ob.OnNext(value));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

then we can write our own `Where<T>` like:

```
public static IObservable<T> Where<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predict)
    {
        ISubject<T> filteredObservable = new TempObservable<T>();
        source.Subscribe(s => { if (predict(s)) { filteredObservable.OnNext(s); } }, () => { filteredObservable.OnCompleted(); }, ex => { filteredObservable.OnError(ex); });
        return filteredObservable;
    }
```

And similar for other useful extension.

Comment: Tried to use this, but it's missing the function `UnSubscribe`. Could you please post this?

Comment: Just posted a version of your answer that works, and does not require `UnSubscribe`. Thanks for this excellent answer!

Comment: @Contango - It does require `UnSubscribe` - your implementation is not correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity Do you know where to get hold of `UnSubscribe`?

Comment: @Contango - All of the source for Rx is freely available. Otherwise you could reverse engineer it fairly easily.

Comment: @Contango - Try this code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/y4Lr2h. I couldn't get "Rx-Main" to load properly so I needed to comment out the `ISubject<T>` implementation, but the `AnonymousDisposable` part works as needed.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated my answer so that it works. FYI, I don't think that this implementation is thread safe, as ForEach() will throw if the collection is modified while it is in the middle of the loop. However, this is fine: my aim is simply to understand how `Subject<T>` works. Thanks ever so much!

Comment: @Contango - It is definitely not thread-safe. It could easily be modifying the collection while looping.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use reactive extensions 1.x which supports .NET 3.5? I believe this was the last release supporting .NET 3.5 SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28018

The source code for rx is also available at http://rx.codeplex.com

Comment: sorry, i re-edit the question, actually for some special reason, I can't use that in our product at least now.

Comment: Dude, the source code for Where is at http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx/NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Where.cs - just have a look. Examine the private class _ (underscore) - it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'll leave this answer in for other readers -originally the OP said he couldn't use .NET 4.0.

Comment: thx, I read the source again but get confused same as the before, the class _ is straitforward: it tests the value in 'OnNext' with the predict, then siginal the observers if true. but how it retrieved the registed Observers in target Observable? We only can add (by call the Subscribe(...)) observers to Observable, but can't get all the added observers, correct? that's probably the key point, could you provide some hint?

Comment: The observable isn't a target, it's the source! IT calls the observer - which in this case is the Where operator. When Where is Subscribed to, it just Subscribes to it's source. I think I have gone as far as I can in this forum - beyond this you are just going to have to study. I suggest www.introtorx.com.

Comment: Where has to track it's Subscribers basically... this is one of the things Observable.Create takes care of... quite a bit for you to re-invent! Don't do it!

Answer (score -2):

This is a working version of the answer by `@Shawn` (his answer is missing the `UnSubscribe<T>` method). Thank you `@Shawn` for the excellent work!

Please note that this is the simplest possible working implementation, in order to understand `Subject<T>`. It is not thread safe.

```
/// <summary>
///     Simplest possible implementation of Subject(T). See http://bit.ly/1QUdpq1.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class TempObservable<T> : ISubject<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<T>> observers = new List<IObserver<T>>();

    #region IObservable<T> Members  
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        this.observers.Add(observer);

        // Could return ".this", but this would introduce an issue: if one subscriber unsubscribed, it would
        // unsubscribe all subscribers.
        return new Unsubscribe<T>(this.observers, observer);
    }
    #endregion


    #region IObserver<T> Members
    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        this.observers.ForEach((ob) => ob.OnNext(value));
    }
    public void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        this.observers.ForEach((ob) => ob.OnError(e));
    }
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        observers.Clear();
    }
}

public class Unsubscribe<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IObserver<T> _observer;
    private readonly List<IObserver<T>> _observers;

    public Unsubscribe(List<IObserver<T>> observers, IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        _observer = observer;
        _observers = observers;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        int index = _observers.IndexOf(_observer);
        _observers.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public static class TempObservable_Test
{
    [Test]
    public static void UnitTest()
    {

        TempObservable<int> x = new TempObservable<int>();
        x.Subscribe(o =>
        {
            Console.Write("Test 1: {0}\n", o);
        });
        var toDispose = x.Subscribe(o =>
        {
            Console.Write("Test 2: {0}\n", o);
        });

        x.OnNext(1);
        toDispose.Dispose();
        x.OnNext(2);
        x.Dispose();
        x.OnNext(3);

        x.Where(o => o == 5).Subscribe(o =>
        {
            Console.Write("Tested: {0}\n", o);
        });
        x.OnNext(4);
        x.OnNext(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an incorrect implementation. The concept of returning `return new UnSubscribe<T>(this.observers, observer);` allows each observer to individually detach itself. By returning `this` you allow any observer to detach all the observers.

Comment: @Enigmativity Good point - where do we get `UnSubscribe<T>` from? I assume this is in an earlier version of Reactive Extensions (RX)?

Comment: @Enigmativity Just fixed said issue by adding `Unsubscribe<T>`. Unit tests perform as expected.